# Eclipse workspace build stuck on "Could not fetch template url from "

Tags: eclipse

I have same issue: (In log this entries in loop)

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2018-08-05 17:31:21.050 !MESSAGE Could not fetch template url from src/main/webapp/components/search/fullView/getit/opac/locationsFilter/locationsFilter.directive.ts
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2018-08-05 17:31:21.052 !MESSAGE Could not fetch template url from src/main/webapp/components/static/static.directive.ts

Files exists and SVN works, but builder cannot get some template URL and freeze on 33%

What it mean "**Could not fetch template url from**" ? From where try to fetch? And what URL? And why try to do it from this specific files in time that eclipse workspace building.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running check disk on windows. 
From begin I feel that have place some file corruption.
It may be cause of many same problems, eclipse or windows don't report about disk corruption.